# Any possible best alternative to this messy explode?

Tags: php, explode

I have a thumb generator script that need me to use define to indicate the path of the folder ... I'm picking a it from a mySQL fild in the form of /images/galleries/name/imagem.jpg

I think I'm doing this the noob way ... there must be a better way of doing this!

```
while($r3 = mysql_fetch_array($e3)){ 
    $path = $r3['pathURLMult'];
    $ped = explode("/", $path);
    $path2 = $ped[0] . "/" . $ped[1] . "/" . $ped[2] . "/";
    define("FOLDER_IMAGES","$path2");
    $imagem = $ped[3];
    echo "<img src=\"getimage.php?img=$imagem&w=280&h=180\" width=\"280\" height=\"180\" />";
}
```

Can someone help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pathinfo();

Try this:

```
while($r3 = mysql_fetch_array($e3)){ 
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($r3['pathURLMult']);
    define("FOLDER_IMAGES",$pathinfo['dirname']);
    echo "<img src=\"getimage.php?img=".$pathinfo['filename']."&w=280&h=180\" width=\"280\" height=\"180\" />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like I wanted and simplified the code a lot! I also didn't know the pathinfo function! Very useful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

That code seems very weird, but without knowing more I guess I won't comment on it.

For the actual question, you can use [`dirname`](http://www.php.net/dirname) and [`basename`](http://www.php.net/basename):

```
$path = dirname($r3['pathURLMult']);
$imagem = basename($r3['pathURLMult']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. You have a define in a loop with a variable definition, a define should only happen once. What's an example value of the variable $r3['pathURLMult'] ? ( btw, $r3, $e3, $ped... I'm sure you could find better variable names ;)

Comment: The query executed could just be for 1 record, I've seen inexperienced programmers use the while() construct for them anyways more than once.

Comment: I know ... but in this case I really need this variable to be defined multiple times!

Comment: No, what i mean is that you CANNOT redefine something you have define()'d already. PHP will throw a NOTICE and the constant will keep the first value you assigned to it. A definition is permanent until the end of the script.